# improve mouse click response speed

Tags: pi-4, mouse

I recently got a new USB mouse to use with my Raspberry Pi 4: [Perixx Perimice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CPW9GZC)

The click response is very slow (I need to hold down the mouse button for over half a second to get it to register). I'm not talking about double clicking, just regular clicking.

The trackball response time seems to be fine, and the mouse click response time seems to be very good on my Windows 10 PC. I don't have any issues with other USB mice on this Raspberry Pi 4...

Is there any settings that can fix this issue?

Comment: What OS are you using?  Is it up to date?

Comment: Also - you are aware this does not say it's compatible with Linux...

Comment: Linux raspberrypi 5.4.51-v7l+ #1333 SMP Mon Aug 10 16:51:40 BST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux. Some commenters claimed it worked well with certain versions of Linux. I was under the impression that a HID USB Mouse device was pretty standardized. I didn't realize there was much difference from a driver level.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `xev` command under X windows to display exactly what input your computer is receiving from the mouse. This won't *solve* your problem, but may assist you to determine if the problem is in software or hardware.

For example, events from your mouse may be delayed getting to the operating system due to busyness on the USB bus. Or a dodgy microswitch may not recognise when you push the button.